# How can I overcome the x509 signed by unknown certificate authority error when using the default Kubernetes API Server virtual IP?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes cluster running in High Availability mode with 3 master nodes. When I try to run the DNS cluster add-on as-is, the `kube2sky` application errors with an x509 signed by unknown certificate authority message for the API Server service address (which in my case is 10.100.0.1). Reading through some of the GitHub issues, it looked like Tim Hockin had fixed this type of issue via using the default service account  tokens available.

All 3 of my master nodes generate their own certificates for the secured API port, so is there something special I need to do configuration-wise on the API servers to get the CA certificate included in the default service account token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be ideal to have the service IP of the API in the SAN field of all your server certificates.

If this is not possible in your setup, set the `clusters{}.cluster.insecure-skip-tls-verify` field to `true` in your [kubeconfig file](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubeconfig-file/), or the pass the `--insecure-skip-tls-verify` flag to `kubectl`.

If you are trying to reach the API from within a pod you could use the secrets mounted via the [Service Account](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/service-accounts/). By default, if you use the default secret, the CA certificate and a signed token are mounted to `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/` in every pod, and any client can use them from within the pod to communicate with the API. This would help you solving the `unknown certificate authority` error and provide you with an easy way to authenticate against your API servers at the same time.

Comment: Hi Antoine, thanks for the answer. Given my current mode of deployment,  I can't really add the service IP to the SAN field since the API server certificates are self-generated (I don't specify the key/cert as flags to the API server). For now, I've gone down the road of using the kubeconfig file for kube2sky that's available on the minion node to talk to the API servers. It just seems to me the service IP for the default Kubernetes service is unusable in it's current state given this error.

Comment: Even if your certs are self-generated, what prevents you from hardcoding the API service IP (which is fixed) in the SAN?

Comment: Because I don't generate them... each of the 3 API servers generates them on startup if a key/cert pair aren't provided. The error I'm getting also isn't about the server IP/domain not matching, it's about the server cert not being signed by a known CA.

Comment: My masters also generate their certs themselves and still have a predefined list of IP/names to include besides the auto-generated ones, it's not incompatible. That said, if you are trying to reach the API from within a pod you could use the secrets mounted via the Service Account. By default, the CA certificate and a signed token are mounted to `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/`, and any client can use them from within the pod to communicate with the API. I will edit my answer with that information.

Comment: How do you define the custom list of IP/names to include? Also, could it have to do with the fact that my kube-system namespace now has 7 default service account tokens? Perhaps the wrong one is being provided to the pods? Given my example of `kube2sky` being the app that's failing, I figure it would know to use the CA cert provided in `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/`, perhaps the wrong CA cert is being provided to it.

Comment: Also, what happens since I'm running my masters in high availability mode with 3 nodes? They each generate their own key/cert pair, presumably with their own self-signed CA cert, but only one CA cert is present in the service account secret... perhaps in HA mode I need to manually generate and provide the key/cert files to the API servers, with the CA cert file concatenated after the key in the key file?

Comment: How to add an extra IP to the SAN of your server certs depends on how you proceed to generate these certs. A script? A configuration management system? In any case it leverages openSSL in the background so you have full freedom. If you have several masters you can have 3 different server certificates but not 3 CA, you should use a single, common CA for your whole cluster. Afaik multiple CAs won't be concatenated. Also having multiple default secrets is a sign that things got reconfigured on the way, and the multiple CAs might interfere.

Comment: OK, thanks. I was confused when you said in a previous comment that your masters generate their certs themselves. Sounds like you have a script to generate the certs... you don't let the Kubernetes API Server self-generate.

Comment: Sorry Bryan, I ignored that the API server was able to generate its own CA. Can you point me to the related documentation page if any? I indeed either call a hand-crafted script or generate my CA using Terraform when I create clusters.

Comment: No worries! See http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kube-apiserver/, and more specifically the help info for the `--tls-cert-file` option.